# Crystal Reports 2008 - Select statement to change background color

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to change the background color using a select/case statement.  However, I need to compare two fields in the same select statement.

{@Color_1} will display "1A" or "2A"
{@Color_2} will display "1B", "2B", "3B", or "4B"

I have tried and I get an error

```
select {@Color_1},{@Color_2}
case "1A": crRed
case "2A": crYellow:
case "1B": crRed
case "2B": crYellow
case "3B": crRed
case "4B": crYellow
default: crNoColor
```

and also tried and none of the fields have color:

```
stringvar tag :={@Color_1};
stringvar tag :={@Color_2};

select tag 
case "1A":
crRed
case "2A":
crYellow
case "1B":
crRed
case "2B":
crYellow
case "3B":
crRed
case "4B":
crYellow
default: crNoColor
```

I have also tried multiple IF, Then, Else combinations and it still does not work.  Can someone provide a solution....PLEASE?!?!

Comment: Are you trying to change the background colors of the {@color_1} and {@color_2} fields or the background of another (third) field?

Comment: I am changing the background color of a third field using the results of {@color_1} and {@color_2}.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few days, so you've probably solved it on your own by now.  If not, try this:

1. Select the field whose background you want to change.
2. For this field, go into it's **Properties** menu, then **Border**, then the **X-2** custom formula button.
3. Try putting your criteria in this format:

> ```
> If
>     {@Color_1}="1A" then crlime  
> else if  
>     {@Color_2}="2b" then cryellow 
> else  
>     crnocolor
> ```

Comment: Actually I haven't solved this yet.  I have one text field that holds multiple team names and I am trying to update the background color based on the teams status.  I have used a multiple If then else statement and for some reason it is not working correctly.  `if {Temp_Status.Team1}="R" then crRed
else if {Temp_Status.Team1}="A" then crYellow
else if {Temp_Status.Team2}="R" then crREd
else if {Temp_Status.Team2}="A" then crYellow
else if {Temp_Status.Team3}="R" then crRed
else if {Temp_Status.Team3}="A" then crYellow
else crNoColor`

Comment: I have this question and this related question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470189/crystal-reports-background-color-does-not-show-up-on-business-objects) regarding the same issue.

Comment: Is this the exact same issue? Because if it is, you should add that information from the other question to this one and delete the old one.  The fact that it disappears when you upload it to BO could be important.